# Showing that dirac delta point charge densities is covariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, dirac-delta-distributions, covariance

Consider a point charge $Q$ with a trajectory of $\textbf{s}(t)$ in frame $O$. The densities are:
$$\rho(\textbf{x},t) = Q\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{s}(t))$$
$$\textbf{J}(\textbf{x},t) = Q\textbf{u}(t)\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{s}(t))$$ where $\textbf{u}(t) = \frac{d\textbf{s}(t)}{dt}$.
By boosting from frame $O$ to $O'$ with arbitrary uniform velocity $\textbf{v} = c\beta$, show that the densities are covariant via explicit calculation.

From:

$$\rho'(\textbf{x}',t') = \gamma(\rho - \frac{1}{c}\beta\cdot\textbf{J}) = \gamma Q \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{s}(t)) (1 - \frac{1}{c}\beta \cdot \textbf{u}(t))$$

Thus, I can need to somehow show that it is the same as for covariance
$$\rho'(\textbf{x}',t') = Q\delta^{(3)'}(\textbf{x}' - \textbf{s}'(t'))$$

However, I am not sure how to show the relation below:
$$\gamma \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{s}(t)) (1 - \frac{1}{c}\beta \cdot \textbf{u}(t)) = \delta^{(3)'}(\textbf{x}' - \textbf{s}'(t'))$$
The usual transformation law of $\delta^{(3)'} = \gamma \delta^{(3)}$ doesn't seem to explain the $(1 - \frac{1}{c}\beta \cdot \textbf{u}(t))$ factor.
I believe showing the relation for $\textbf{J}'$ would also follow similar argument.

Comment: Related if not Duplicate : [Why does it follow that the Dirac delta function is a scalar "because determinant of the Lorentz transformation is 1"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635015/why-does-it-follow-that-the-dirac-delta-function-is-a-scalar-because-determinan/635059#635059).

Answer (score 0):

That the four dimensional delta function is a scalar follows from its integral representation (4-D Fourier transform)
\begin{equation}
\delta^{(4)}(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{-ik_\mu x^\mu}d^4 x.
\end{equation}